# Get the parent tag based on the child tag in Jsoup?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Is there a way to get the parent tag based on the child tag in Jsoup ?
Eg: I want to get the tags which have an `li` as child.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Is this select expression suitable `*:has(li)` ?

Comment: Please post some small examples of the html you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsoup: How to select the parent nodes, which have children satisfying a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001212/jsoup-how-to-select-the-parent-nodes-which-have-children-satisfying-a-conditio)

Comment: @vikingsteve that will select all the tags which will have li as child, along with some other tags also as the sibling of li... :-)

Comment: @LittlePanda sir actually I was looking for a single line query using select method, dont wanna use parent actually, but thanx for the help...

Comment: Please add your html code to the question.