# read td class from url using java

Tags: java

hello i need little help reading website content

i want to read

```
    <tr>
<td class="text-center"><strong>This Month</strong></td>
<td class="text-center">1194</td>
<td class="text-center">22</td>
<td class="text-center">7</td>
</tr>
```

i make it like this but it always return nothing

```
if (url.toLowerCase().contains("top100arena.com") && line.contains("<strong>This Month</strong></td><td class=\"text-center\">"))
                        return Integer.valueOf(line.split(">")[1].replace("</td", "").replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: Given the input above, you probably want to change `line.contains("<strong>This Month</strong></td><td class=\"text-center\">")` to `line.contains("<td class=\"text-center\"><strong>This Month</strong></td>")` ?

Comment: i want to read this line <td class="text-center">1194</td>

Comment: Use jsoup or other HTML-parsing library to help you parse the HTML

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are considering using third-party libraries, jsoup is a good idea.

https://jsoup.org/

using css / xpath selectors, you can indicate the element you are interested in, e.g.

```
//tr/td[contains (strong,.)]
```

will find all bold entries, then we can get the parent for that element, and read all the elements

http://xpather.com/

https://devhints.io/xpath

[jsoup: How to select the parent nodes, which have children satisfying a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001212/jsoup-how-to-select-the-parent-nodes-which-have-children-satisfying-a-conditio)